# How create recursive loop for parsing the json?

Tags: python, json, django, python-2.7, django-1.11

I use [Nestable2](https://github.com/RamonSmit/Nestable2) plugin in my Django project to create tree.

When user change the order of tree nodes, plugin return me JSON which I send by Ajax to server.

Nestable2 return me JSON:

```
[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3,"children":[{"id":4},{"id":5,"foo":"bar"}]}]
```

In Django view I take this JSON but I want to parse it to list of ids. For example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...]
```

It seems to me I need to create recursive loop for this task, so I am little bit confused. Can someone say the best way to make this task?

**views.py:**

```
class NodeOrderView(CsrfExemptMixin, JsonRequestResponseMixin, FormView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.request_json)  # JSON
        return self.render_json_response({'saved': 'ok'})
```

Comment: Its not quite clear exactly, what you want. Flatten a `JSON` structure to the  `id`'s of each element?

Comment: Hello! :) Question looks simple but I am confused. In post you can see example of JSON which I send to server by ajax. I want to create list of ids from this JSON in my `views.py` file. That list of ids I expect to use for other purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question. This should do what you want. Or at least point you in the right direction.

```
json_array = [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3,"children":[{"id":4},{"id":5,"foo":"bar"}]}]

def get_ids(json_array):
    ids = []
    for obj in json_array:
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            ids.append(obj.get('id'))
            children = obj.get('children', None)
            if children:
                ids.extend(get_ids(children))
        elif isinstance(obj, list):
            ids.extend(get_ids(obj))
    return ids
```

---

```
>>> get_ids(json_array)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you, bro! :) Your generic method take into account different depth of nesting. Works great!

Comment: No problem, be careful. I'd test it properly and tweak it as necessary.

Comment: Why you are afraid? What can go wrong for your opinion? I tested with 
different levels of tree nesting and it seems work great.

Comment: For instance if there is no 'children' attribute, you could get a `KeyError`. Or the `id` for a particular object is labeled `something_id`. Or  the nesting is greater than the recursion limit. Or one of your objects is a subclass of `dict` or `list`. There could be loads to go wrong...